# Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then $X \cup Y$ is finite and $| X \cup Y| \leq |X| + |Y|$.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Let us assume that they are distinct at least, for otherwise $X \cup Y = X$ and $X$ is finite. Also let us assume that $X$ has cardinality $n$ and $Y$ has cardinality $m$. We can also assume that $n \leq m$ without loss of generality because we can swap the roles of $n$ and $m$.

Because $X$ and $Y$ are finite we know there exist bijections $f,g$ defined as follows   $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{N_n}$ $g:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{N_m}$.

To show that $X \cup Y$ is finite, we must show the existence of a bijection $h:X \cup Y \rightarrow \mathbb{N_p}$ defined as follows:
$$
   h(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       f(x) & : x \in X\\
       g(x) + n & : x \notin X
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
Where $p \leq n+m$.

At this point I am not sure whether I have even defined a correct bijection. I seem to think it is correct. But even assuming its correct I am running into trouble in attempting to proof it is a bijection.

I start by saying:

I now attempt to show that $h$ is surjective.

suppose $k \in \mathbb{N_p}$.
If $k \leq n$ then $k \in \mathbb{N_n}$ and is the image of some $x \in X$ as defined by the bijection $f$.

If $n+1 \leq k \leq p$ then $n+1 \leq k \leq n+m$ and so $1\leq k-n\leq m$. From this I can deduce that $k -n$ is in the image of $g$ and since $g$ is a bijection there exists $y \in Y$ such that $g(y) = k - n$, that is
$g(y)+n = k.$ and so we have found, in each case an element $x\in X \cup Y$ such that $h(x) = k$ therefore $h$ is surjective.

Now to show that $h$ is injective.

Let $x,y \in X \cup Y $ and $h(x) = h(y) = k$ if $ k \leq n$ then

$$h(x) = h(y) = k \implies f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$$

if $n+1 \leq k \leq p \implies 1 \leq k - n \leq m $ and so

$$h(x) - n = h(y) - n = k - n \in \mathbb{N_m} \implies g(x) = g(y) \implies x =y$$

and so $h$ is injective. Hence $h$ is a bijection and$X \cup Y$ is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition, $h(x)$ takes on values in $\mathbb{N}_{n+m}$ and unless $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ it does not take on all values in $\mathbb{N}_p$. For example if $g(x)=1$ and $x\in X$, then $n+1$ is not present in $h$.

We can say that each element of $\mathbb{N}_p$ is mapped via $h$ to a unique element in $\mathbb{N}_{n+m}$, so the function $h$ is injective.

To prove $h$ is surjective, we can use your original proof.

Comment: I am a little unclear, what you are saying? that h is not defined correctly?

Comment: @hmparticle; no, h is fine - you have defined g on Y, not on 'not X' so you just need to be careful with definitions. your g takes $x\not\in X$ and reads it as an element of Y, because $x\in X\cup Y-X (\ne Y)$

Comment: Ah, thanks. sorry I was just making sure. Thanks for the confirmation. That was what was required :).

Answer (score 2):

Use that
$|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|$

Comment: I have not yet shown that the intersection of sets is finite. Can i still use that equality?

Comment: If your sets $X$ and $Y$ are finite then $X\cap Y$ is also finite because $X\cap Y\subset X$

Comment: Silly me, perfect, that answers the inequality in my question :). Could you check the validity of my attempt at proving the existence of the bijection $h$ please? +1